# imagen con extencion .0

Tags: imagen

estaba en la plataforma de twitch viendo sus imagenes y vi algo curioso, que sus emotes son extenciones .0 (punto cero)

y quiero saber exactamente que es un archivo .0 y en que se suele usar

la ruta: https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/112290/1.0

y se muestra esta imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que eso es una url con un "content-type image", basicamente es como mostrar una imagen dentro de una web, eso se hace para ocultar la verdadera ruta de la imagen para que los "hackers" no se pongan creativos.

Comment: como podría ponerlo en mi pagina web?